# Tuning UDP-lite protocol instead of UDP with "IPERF" tool

Tags: iperf

How do i test network connection for UDP-Lite protocol (along with checksum coverage) instead of UDP with "IPerf" tool.

for udp we use following command-> 
 iperf -s -u -i 1

what command should i use for udp-lite protocol.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [patched IPERF](http://www.erg.abdn.ac.uk/~gerrit/udp-lite/)  compile, and then run:

```
# iperf -s --udplite 0
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP-Lite port 5001
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP-Lite datagram buffer size:  160 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

From help:

```
  -u, --udp                use UDP      as transport; no argument may follow
  -u  --udplite   #        use UDP-Lite as transport; arg: cscov (0=full coverage)
```